# Descartian summation of two numpy arrays of different length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum, numpy-ndarray

Is there anyway to add two numpy arrays of different length in a Descartian fashion without iterating over columns `a`? See example below.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]])
c = dec_sum(a, b) # c = np.array([[[2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5]], [[4, 4], [5, 6], [6, 7]]])
```

Given a `2x2` numpy array `a` and `3x2` numpy array `b`, `c= dec_sum(a, b)` and `c` is `2x3x2`.

Comment: Check out numpy broadcasting: `a[None, ...] + b[:,None,:]`.

Comment: thanks, actually this worked
`def descarty_sum(a, b):    return a[:, None] + b[None, :]`